# Worksheet_Change Moving Between Sheets

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook that I use to collect shipping data.  I have a Worksheet_Change macro that moves the active cell based on its location.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  If ActiveCell.Column = 4 Then
    ActiveCell.Offset(-1, -1).Select
  ElseIf ActiveCell.Column = 3 Then
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
    Sheet2.Activate
    Call Sheet5.Last_Row_Range
    ThisWorkbook.Save
  End If
End Sub
```

The changes are initiated by scanning a number into an active cell.
I would now like the code to look at an adjacent cell, after the scan, and based on that cells content, select another Worksheet.  Ie; if `ActiveCell.Offset=x` select sheet1 else if `ActiveCell.Offset=y` select sheet2.

Thanks for taking the time to read this.

Comment: Welcome to SO. You've only mentioned what you like your code to do. You have not shown how you have tried to accomplish it nor where you are stuck. Effectively, you haven't asked an *actual question*. Read [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to get more effective help.

Comment: This was my first post here.  Sorry for not posting correctly.  After working on this for a few days, I have found a solution.             ** Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  If ActiveCell.Column = 131 And ActiveCell.Offset(-1, -124) = "FED" Then
        Sheet6.Activate
    
  Else
  
  If ActiveCell.Column = 131 And ActiveCell.Offset(-1, -124) = "UPS" Then
       Sheet5.Activate
       
         
  End If
  End If
  ThisWorkbook.Save
End Sub**